# React + Redux: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I am trying to implement an action that asyncronously get the current user online from my Rails Backend, by using axios. 
When it successfully gives the response: I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```

Here is what the response.data looks like:

```
user: {
id: 4,
first_name: Julien,
last_name: Corb,
is_subscribed: true
}
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export default store;
```

actions.js

```
import { CREATE_USER, PROPAGATE_LOGIN, PROPAGATE_LOGOUT } from "./actionTypes";
import axios from 'axios';

export const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get("/users/get_current_user", {})
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.user) {
        dispatch(propagateLogin(...response.data)); //the error occurs here
      } else {
         dispatch(propagateLogout());
       }
    });
  };
};

export const propagateLogin = (user) => ({
  type: PROPAGATE_LOGIN,
  payload: {
    user
  }
});

export const propagateLogout = () => ({
  type: PROPAGATE_LOGOUT,
  payload: { }
});
```

users.js reducer:

```
import { CREATE_USER, PROPAGATE_LOGIN, PROPAGATE_LOGOUT } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  user: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_USER: {

    }
    case PROPAGATE_LOGIN: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      }
    }
    case PROPAGATE_LOGOUT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

It is the first time I get this error, I feel like there is something wrong with setting the initial user state to `null`; but the problem might be also something else.

Comment: `dispatch(propagateLogin(...response.data.user));

Comment: `case CREATE_USER` does not have a `break` or `return` statement. is that intended?

Comment: @jsw324 is does not work; thank you for your help though! @ B12Toaster it is just that it isn't implemented yet.

Comment: why are using spread in `...response.data` doesn't `response.data` work?

Comment: Agreed with Amir, just use `response.data` and use `payload: user`in your action creator

Comment: I was previously updating state locally inside the component by using the spread operator. But you're right this seems to be the problem ! Thank you @Amir-Mousavi !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've found a solution to your specific problem but here's an explanation of the error:

In your example you attempt to spread an object using the syntax intended for iterable objects. The correct syntax for **object** spread is `const clone = {...original}` (or `dispatch(propagateLogin({...response.data}));` in the OP's case) which essentially iterates over the keys of the original object and copies the original's key/value pairs into a new object literal.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax)

For function calls:
`myFunction(...iterableObj);`

For array literals or strings:
`[...iterableObj, '4', 'five', 6];`

For object literals (new in ECMAScript 2018):
`let objClone = { ...obj };`